# Múltiplas Views com AngularJS e Ionic

Tags: html5, angularjs, ionic

Estou tentando adicionar algumas states no meu código para navegar entre elas, porém não consigo, as únicas que funcionam são as views que vem da barra lateral. Segue código:

app.js:

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.search', {
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
      }
    }
  })

    .state('app.principal', {
      url: '/principal',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/principal.html',
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.principal.vendas', {
      url: '/vendas',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/vendas.html',
        }
      }
    });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/principal');
});
```

Principal.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Principal">
  <ion-content>
    <h3 style="font-family: Helvetica">Bem vindo ao E-Management Mobile.</h3>

      <img src="./img/logo_grupoviceri.png" class="item-image" style="width:100%">

    <div class="row">
    <button class="button button-block button-viceri-C">
      Vendas
      <i class="ion-ios-pie-outline" style="font-size: 170%"></i>
        <a href="#/app/vendas"></a>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <button class="button button-block button-viceri-C">
      Operação 
      <i class="ion-gear-b" style="font-size: 170%"></i>
    </button>
  </div>

      <div ui-view></div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Vendas.html:

```
<ion-nav-view view-title="Vendas">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <ion-pane>
        <!--HEADER DO APP-->
      <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
          <button class="button button-icon icon ion-arrow-left-c"></button>
        <h1 class="title center">Vendas</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

        <!--CONTEUDO CENTRAL DO APP-->
      <ion-content>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="button-bar">
                <a class="button button-viceri-C">Listas</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Ou seja, meu app é iniciado na Principal, e ao clicar em os dos botoes Vendas ou Operação, eu deveria ser redirecionado para Vendas, porém, não está funcionado. O que fiz de errado?
Agradeço desde já.
PS:Operação ainda não está implementada.

Comment: Onde ta  `url: '/vendas',` e  `url: '/principal',` coloca `url: '/app/vendas',` e  `url: '/app/principal',`

Answer (score 0):

Seguinte caso suas as views correspondentes as states não estiverem dentro da pasta #/app/... ou devam ser mostradas fora do menu lateral você deve criar um novo state que não herde de app.algumaCoisa pois se ela herdar deverá estar na mesma pasta que os demais template.
EX:

```
.state('vendas', {
    url: '/vendas',
    abstract: false,
    templateUrl: 'templates/vendas.html',
    controller: 'VendasCtrl'
  })
```

desde que seja criada corretamente a view dentro da pasta templates com o nome vendas.html isso deverá funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Simples.

Vc navega entre states com `ui-sref='myState'`

Tente:

```
<button class="button button-block button-viceri-C">
  Vendas
  <i class="ion-ios-pie-outline" style="font-size: 170%"></i>
    <a ui-sref="vendas"></a>
</button>
```